# Django model querying for first N rows that sum up to a given number

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-q

I am sing Django 3.2

I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    num_visits  = models.PositiveSmallNumber()
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_at']
```

I want to select the first N rows where the **CUMULATIVE SUM** of the number of visits = 100 (as an example)
A trivial (but probably DB intensive way) to do it would be to iterate through the rows in the table (i.e. elements of the queryset) - but I don't want to do that - for reasons that should be obvious.

How can I write a query that fetches the first N rows where the SUM of visits is a specified number?

```
def get_rows_satisfying_visit_count(cumulative_sum_in_field=100):
    MyModel.objects.filter(/* what ? */)
```

Comment: I have edited the question to make more clear that it is the minimum number of rows that have a **CUMULATIVE SUM** of a field, that I am seeking to retrieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the slice operator for the queryset:

```
def get_rows_satisfying_visit_count(visits=100, rows=100):
    return MyModel.objects.filter(num_visits=number)[:rows]
```

EDIT:
With the updated question, from Django >= 2.0, you can do this with `Window` and `Sum`:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    cumulative_sum=Window(
        Sum('num_visits'),
        order_by=F('id').asc()
    )
).filter(cumulative_sum__lte=100)
```

This will get the first few rows that have the cumulative sum less than or equal to 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
def get_rows_satisfying_visit_count(number=100):
    MyModel.objects.filter(num_visits=number)[:N]
```

The queryset will only return the first N elements that satisfy the num_visits condition.
You might think that it will return all the objects satisfying the condition and then slice but in reality, a LIMIT database operation is being performed so it satifies your DB intensity condition.
You can check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets for more info.